# Validation errors handling from EJB in JSF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I would like to know what is the best way to handle validation errors in medium/big Java EE application.

Suppose I have managed bean and facade as it is below.

```
class SomeManagedBean {

    @EJB
    SomeFacade someFacade;

    public void performSomeAction() {
        (...)
        someFacade.businessAction(loggedUser, editedEntity);
        (...)
    }

}

class SomeFacadeImpl {

    public Object businessAction(User user, Entity entity) {
        if (!isInCorrectStateToDoAction(entity)) {
            // error A
        }
        (...)
        if (!hasRightToDoAction(user, entity)) {
            // error X
        }

        doAction(user, entity);
    }

}
```

I expect that businessAction from SomeFacade should validate their inputs and check if it can do this business action with given arguments. It's because I may use this business method in several places in application and I do not want copy validation code.

Suppose I would like to use FacesMessage to provide to client informations about validation errors.

Some solutions:

- exceptions - when something is wrong with arguments I simply throw an Exception

  - so I have to throw IncorrectStateForActionException, NoRightToDoActionException
  - why not: I can throw only one exception so I can't notify user about several things: "You don't have rights", (...), "Entity is incorrect state"
  - beside exception shouldn't be used to provide logic of our application
- some Result class

  ```
  class Result<T> {
      T returnedValueFromMethod;

      List<ProcessingError> errors;
  }
  ```

  - now definition of my business method looks like:

    ```
    public Result<Object> businessAction(User user, Entity entity)
    ```
  - when something is wrong I add error information to Result
  - when everything is all right I put returned value to my Result object and return this object
  - why not: this seems like kind of "error code" in pretty complex structure. Because of that recommendation which tells "change error codes into exception" it's understandable why we would like to avoid it.
- we can do validation in facade and controller

  - why not: duplicated code
- validation only in controller and action in facade

  - why not: it could be dangerous when we use this businessAction method from other place in code
- we can do two methods in facade: validation and action (Query Command Separation)

  - result from validation should contain every possible error which may occur so it's pretty strange structure
- we can do several methods for validation (errors from A to X)

  - it's easy to provide error messages
  - but this solutions seems just stupid
- any other ideas?

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do authentication/validation in business layer and let it throw an exception in case of failure. You can just handle it in JSF action method.

E.g.

```
@EJB
private SomeService service;

public void someAction() {
    try {
        service.doSomething();
        addGlobalInfoFacesMessage("Doing something succeed!");
    } catch (SomeBusinessException e) {
        addGlobalErrorFacesMessage("Doing something failed with {0}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Or, you can let it go and have the container handle it by an `<error-page>` on the specific `<exception-type>`.

As to performing authentication and validation all by itself, the Java EE stack offers annotations like JAAS `@RolesAllowed` for authentication and JSR303 `@NotNull`, `@Size`, etc for model. This should reduce the `if` check boilerplate inside the service methods itself.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not enough. (1) As I said before: I would like to avoid using exceptions to control flow of program, (2) no matter if I use JAAS (that's too late for that) or Java Bean Validation there will be many possible, diffrent errors from method in EJB. And I would like inform user about all of them instead about this which will be validated firstly

Comment: (3) As for the error pages, I would like user to stay at page where he was and provide him ability to correct errors/mistakes.